# Tika Parser is treating .pptx text content as embedded image

Tags: java, parsing, powerpoint, apache-tika, tika-server

I am using tika parser to validate the content of various file types like .docx, .txt, .pptx and many more others. It seems that even for a normal text content pptx file, when running tika parser on it, its responding saying embedded image in file. Same Autodetect parser is working fine with .docx and other file extensions. Any special changes needs to be done for pptx file here? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Apache` `POI`? https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ and https://poi.apache.org/components/document/

Comment: Also, this will be closed as `Needs more focus` if you don't add an example app that shows what you are doing.

Comment: I guess `Tika` uses `POI`. We need to see what you did.

Comment: Tika does include embedded image names in the extracted text, if that's what you're seeing.  I agree with @SedJ601, we need more info to help.  How are you running Tika, how is it saying "embedded image in file"?

Comment: @TimAllison SedJ601
 I am using a generic code for docx, pptx and other extensions which is like this. AutoDetect Parser to parse the content and before that overriding EmbeddedDocumentExtractor method shouldParseEmbedded to check if embedded image is there or not. Parser parser  = new AutoDetectParser() override Boolean shouldParseEmbedded(Metadata metadata ) and checking mimeType is of image content type or not. This is working fine for all other docs, but for pptx, this mimeType is showing image/jpeg even for a simple hi text. Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing i found, its taking thumbnail here whose type is jpeg during parsing , i checked in metadata its saying "docProps/thumbnail.jpeg". Hopefully there should be some configuration in OfficeParserConfig to turn off this or something like this...

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Y, we can add a "skipThumbnails" or similar? Please open an issue on our JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA When you request an account, please reference this SO link.

Comment: sure, yea we can add a property to validate key named "dc:title" in metadata and its value as "/docProps/thumbnail.jpeg" to skip thumbnails. I will raise a JIRA, thanks.